# Hyper-V client - drive periodically unwritable

Tags: hard-drive, virtual-machine, hyper-v, windows-server-2008-r2, vhdx

I have an odd situation. A file server that has been in place for about 10 months suddenly has a drive that is periodically unwritable.

Host

- Dell Poweredge R420
- Server 2012 R2
- 32 GB RAM
- Xeon(R) CPU E5-2420

Guest

- Server 2012 R2
- min. 2048 GB RAM (dynamic)
- 4 cores
- 5 vhdx drives

  - 1 on physical drive of server
  - 4 on individual LUNs on QNAP (TS-853A with 4.4.1.1117 f/w)

Periodically, one of the vhdx files stored on the QNAP will become unwritable. They can still be read, however.
It is hard to determine how often it happens, but it may occur every few minutes.
Sometimes write access resumes without any interaction.
Sometimes rebooting restores write access.
So far I have been unable to find any logs indicating a problem on the host, the guest, or the QNAP.

Restoring the VHDX from backup does not resolve the issue permanently. 
Restoring the full VM does not resolve the issue.
Restoring the full VM, or just the VHDX file, to a different hoist does not resolve the issue.
Mounting the restored VHDX directly on the host has the same issues.

I have created a new VHDX file and am restoring the files and folders from backup to it.

As near as I can tell, Google has never heard of this issue.

Any thoughts, ideas, solutions?

Comment: Are these QNAP LUNs are used only by VM or they are connected also to other systems/VMs?

Comment: They are only connected to a single server.
One host. One vm.

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved by creating a new VHDX file and moving all data from the old VHDX to the new VHDX and mounting the new VHDX in place of the old one on the virtual machine. 
It appears that somehow the VHDX itself was corrupt in some way. 
Creating a new one worked. 
Restoring one from backup did not work

Comment: If it happens again, you might want to run a complete memory check. Peace